# Is Android unit testing on a physical device actually a thing?

Tags: cpu

Firebase has physical devices for testing: https://firebase.google.com/docs/test-lab/android/available-testing-devices however it's a little expensive.

I was wondering if testing things on a physical Android device is a real thing and if there are frameworks for that. I know that there are unit tests that are mocked and run on the computer, but some things like the Android Media Codec Decoder can only be tested on the device

Comment: Not sure if this is a development topic or not. That said, real devices should be used for testing due to differences in chipsets/OS versions/OEM customizations that can't be done via emulator. Since [scrcpy](https://github.com/Genymobile/scrcpy) exists to drive a device from a PC, other projects like [Smartphone Test Farm](https://github.com/openstf/stf) appear to aim for similar utility to be used at some scale within a business. Also just noticed the same question on SO. Generally physical device test is for things which can be affected by prior listed items.

Comment: what is your question? Define "actually a thing".